# Windows Server 2003 : Unable to load

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, hard-drive, bios

I had a physical server installed windows server 2003, it appear to be unable to load into windows, I tried diagnose it from Boot Disk Utilities and notice all the results return was failed.

Is that mean anything? and how can I solve if unable to load the windows?

I believe this is quite a common issue of server failure, please help.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried booting into Safe Mode?

Comment: Does it give an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your drive is toast to me - in which case, you're out of luck.

That said, could provide some more information such as what hardware you're using, what error messages are appearing and what the output from the Boot Disk Utilities was.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of possible Solutions for Blue Screen after the boot menu :

RAID Failure - It could be that if you have a RAID 1 setup then the RAID has failed.  It is possible that windows is trying to boot from the failed drive.  Try booting from each drive seperately and see if one is working correctly.

Other Hardware Failure - We have a number of servers that will not allow windows to boot if they have a fan failure - windows will report that it has shut down to protect the system from damage.